# How can I add data to CRUD in Vaadin by using setItems for grid?

Tags: spring, jpa, vaadin, crud

I'm going to add data to a CRUD component in Vaadin. It's an easy question here.
But the issue I got is that I cannot add data to the CRUD by first getting the `grid` object and then set its items to it.

Here is my Vaadin class. This class begins first to get data from a JPA Spring database. OK. That's works. And the data is transfered into a collection named `crudData`. Then the `crudData` is beings set to `crud.getGrid().setItems(crudData);` and that's not working. I assume that if I get the grid from the CRUD, then I can set the grid items as well too and then they will show up on the CRUD....but no...

```
@Data
public class StocksCrud {

    private Crud<StockNames> crud;

    private List<StockNames> crudData;

    private StockNamesRepository stockNamesRepository;


    private CrudEditor<StockNames> createStocksEditor() {
        TextField stockName = new TextField("Name of the stock");
        FormLayout form = new FormLayout(stockName);

        Binder<StockNames> binder = new Binder<>(StockNames.class);
        binder.bind(stockName, StockNames::getStockName, StockNames::setStockName);

        return new BinderCrudEditor<>(binder, form);
    }

    public StocksCrud(StockNamesRepository stockNamesRepository) {
        this.stockNamesRepository = stockNamesRepository;

        // Fill the crud
        crudData = new ArrayList<StockNames>();
        for(StockNames stockName: stockNamesRepository.findAll()) {
            crudData.add(new StockNames(stockName.getId(), stockName.getStockName()));
        }

        // Crate crud table
        crud = new Crud<>(StockNames.class, createStocksEditor());
        crud.getGrid().setItems(crudData); // This won't work
        crud.addSaveListener(e -> saveStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.addDeleteListener(e -> deleteStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.getGrid().removeColumnByKey("id");
        crud.addThemeVariants(CrudVariant.NO_BORDER);
    }

    private void deleteStock(StockNames stockNames) {
        boolean exist = stockNamesRepository.existsBystockName(stockNames.getStockName());
        if(exist == true) {
            crudData.remove(stockNames);
            stockNamesRepository.delete(stockNames);
        }
    }

    private void saveStock(StockNames stockNames) {
        System.out.println(stockNames == null);
        System.out.println(stockNamesRepository == null);
        boolean exist = stockNamesRepository.existsBystockName(stockNames.getStockName());
        if(exist == false) {
            crudData.add(stockNames);
            stockNamesRepository.save(stockNames);
        }
    }   

}
```

Here is my error output:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.component.crud.CrudFilter cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.function.SerializablePredicate
```

I know that there is a way to set data to CRUD in Vaadin, by using a data provider class. But I don't want to use that. It's....to much code. I want to keep it clean and write less code in Java. Example here at the bottom: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-crud/java-examples

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StockNames implements Cloneable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String stockName;

    public StockNames(int id, String stockName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

This is my code now

```
@Data
public class StocksCrud {

    private Crud<StockNames> crud;

    private List<StockNames> crudData;

    private StockNamesRepository stockNamesRepository;


    private CrudEditor<StockNames> createStocksEditor() {
        TextField stockName = new TextField("Name of the stock");
        FormLayout form = new FormLayout(stockName);

        Binder<StockNames> binder = new Binder<>(StockNames.class);
        binder.bind(stockName, StockNames::getStockName, StockNames::setStockName);

        return new BinderCrudEditor<>(binder, form);
    }

    public StocksCrud(StockNamesRepository stockNamesRepository) {
        this.stockNamesRepository = stockNamesRepository;

        // Fill the crud
        crudData = new ArrayList<StockNames>();
        for(StockNames stockName: stockNamesRepository.findAll()) {
            crudData.add(new StockNames(stockName.getId(), stockName.getStockName()));
        }

        // Create grid
        Grid<StockNames> grid = new Grid<StockNames>();
        grid.setItems(crudData);

        // Crate crud table
        crud = new Crud<>(StockNames.class, createStocksEditor());
        crud.setGrid(grid);
        crud.addSaveListener(e -> saveStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.addDeleteListener(e -> deleteStock(e.getItem()));
        //crud.getGrid().removeColumnByKey("id");
        crud.addThemeVariants(CrudVariant.NO_BORDER);
    }

    private void deleteStock(StockNames stockNames) {
        boolean exist = stockNamesRepository.existsBystockName(stockNames.getStockName());
        if(exist == true) {
            crudData.remove(stockNames);
            stockNamesRepository.delete(stockNames);
        }
    }

    private void saveStock(StockNames stockNames) {
        System.out.println(stockNames == null);
        System.out.println(stockNamesRepository == null);
        boolean exist = stockNamesRepository.existsBystockName(stockNames.getStockName());
        if(exist == false) {
            crudData.add(stockNames);
            stockNamesRepository.save(stockNames);
        }
    }   

}
```

**Update 2:**

This gives an error.

```
// Create grid
        Grid<StockNames> grid = new Grid<StockNames>();
        StockNames s1 = new StockNames(1, "HELLO");
        crudData.add(s1);
        grid.setItems(crudData);

        // Crate crud table
        crud = new Crud<>(StockNames.class, createStocksEditor());
        crud.setGrid(grid);
        crud.addSaveListener(e -> saveStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.addDeleteListener(e -> deleteStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.getGrid().removeColumnByKey(grid.getColumns().get(0).getKey());
        crud.addThemeVariants(CrudVariant.NO_BORDER);
```

The error is:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0'
```

What? I just added a object.

Comment: Check if this info helps https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17480248/exception-using-vaadin-crud-with-listdataprovider, it seems to be related to a known issue https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-crud-flow/issues/164 So if it is the same problem the solution is to instantiate Grid and use crud.setGrid, etc.

Comment: @TatuLund Nope. If I add `crud.setDataProvider(new ListDataProvider<StockNames>(stockNamesRepository.findAll()));` then I get the same error as above.

Comment: @TatuLund It gives not error if I add `Grid<StockNames> grid = new Grid<StockNames>();
  grid.setItems(crudData);` and then set that `grid` to the `crud` object. But I cannot se any rows in my crud. The database shows rows, but not the crud object.

Comment: @TatuLund Also `crud.getGrid().removeColumnByKey("id");` gives error because I cannot remove the column key id.

Comment: @TatuLund I added the `StockNames` class as well into the question.

Comment: shouldn't `crud.getGrid().setItems(..);` result in NPE as the crud does not yet have a grid at this point? try passing a `new CrudGrid<StockNames>(StockNames.class, false)` as parameter to `new Crud(..)`

Comment: @KasparScherrer Is there any working example for CrudGrid? Cannot find any example.

Comment: @KasparScherrer If I try to passing that parameter, then I need to change the whole CRUD code in Vaadin.

Comment: a normal `Grid<StockNames>` should do just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning grid fixes the issue

```java
 Grid<StockNames> grid=new Grid<>(StockNames.class);
 crud = new Crud<>(StockNames.class,grid, createStocksEditor());
```

---

In your code example you are relying on default implementation provided by `Crud`, thus [`CrudGrid` is getting created](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-crud-flow/blob/master/vaadin-crud-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/crud/Crud.java#L309). Its [setDataProvider](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/crud/CrudGrid.html#setDataProvider-com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataProvider-) returns `DataProvider<E,CrudFilter>`, whereas Grid's DataProvider is of type: `AbstractDataProvider<T, SerializablePredicate<T>>` (This is because you are using `ListDataProvider`, which extends `AbstractDataProvider<T, SerializablePredicate<T>>`). This is what error states:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.flow.component.crud.**CrudFilter** cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.function.**SerializablePredicate**

So if you want to assign values via grid- you would first need to create one. Otherwise, as shown in the docs you could provide a custom dataprovider: [PersonDataProvider](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-crud/java-examples)

**Update**

---

This is an example code I am using. Adding a new item in Crud works, after I have added a no-args constructor to the bean:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class StockNames implements Cloneable{
    Random rnd=new Random();
    private int id;
    private String stockName;

    public StockNames(){
        //You will an id generated automatically for you, but here is just an example
        id=rnd.nextInt(12000);

    }

    public StockNames(int id, String stockName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }
}
```

and the `StockCrud` class:

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.crud.*;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Route("crudLayout")
public class StockCrud extends VerticalLayout {

    private Crud<StockNames> crud;

    private List<StockNames> crudData;


    private CrudEditor<StockNames> createStocksEditor() {
        TextField stockName = new TextField("Name of the stock");
        FormLayout form = new FormLayout(stockName);

        Binder<StockNames> binder = new Binder<>(StockNames.class);
        binder.bind(stockName, StockNames::getStockName, StockNames::setStockName);

        return new BinderCrudEditor<>(binder, form);
    }

    public StockCrud() {

        // Fill the crud
        crudData = new ArrayList<StockNames>();
        for(int i=0;i<150;i++) {
            crudData.add(new StockNames(i,"Name " + i));
        }

        // Crate crud table
        Grid<StockNames> grid=new Grid<>(StockNames.class);
        crud = new Crud<>(StockNames.class,grid, createStocksEditor());
        //((CrudGrid )crud.getGrid()).setItems(crudData);
        crud.getGrid().setItems(crudData); // This won't work
        crud.addSaveListener(e -> saveStock(e.getItem()));
        crud.addDeleteListener(e -> deleteStock(e.getItem()));
       // crud.getGrid().removeColumnByKey("id");
        crud.addThemeVariants(CrudVariant.NO_BORDER);
        add(crud);
    }

    private void deleteStock(StockNames stockNames) {
       // if(crudData.contains(stockNames)) {
            crudData.remove(stockNames);
        //}
    }

    private void saveStock(StockNames stockNames) {
        System.out.println(stockNames == null);
        if(!crudData.contains(stockNames)) {
            crudData.add(stockNames);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry. Your code snippet won't display any lists. I have updated my code right now. The code gives no error by the way.

Comment: I added another update too with error message. It seems that even if I add a row, it won't become included in the crud.

Comment: Well, I think it happens because you are setting Grid using ` new Grid<StockNames>();`, In the snippet above I am using [`new Grid<>(StockNames.class);`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html#Grid-java.lang.Class-) , which also generates columns based on bean class. If you want to use your constructor instead, you should also add the columns manually. They will not be pre-generated

Comment: @DanielMårtensson take a look at my update :)  I have added classes I am using. Could you also, please, put the whole stacktrace for your `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I have read your message. I till try your solution and give you a reply later.

Comment: Yes that's working! Thank you so much! You are great! :)